# Initialisation of a std::string seems to generate the same code no matter which initialisation I use (uniform, assignment, etc)

Tags: c++11, initialization, c++17

I was experimenting with `C++ Insights` and I got a result that was surprising to me and which I don't really understand. I was hoping some one can provide some illumination for.

Given this code snippet:

```
#include <string> 

int main()
{
  std::string a {"123"};
  std::string b = {"123"};
  std::string c = "123";
  std::string d("123");
}
```

I was at least expecting `a` to be initialised differently to `c`. With `c` I was expecting some sort of temporary string to be copied and for `a` I was expecting just the constructor to be called directly.

Here is the link to `c++ insights`: [here](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPHN0cmluZz4gCgppbnQgbWFpbigpCnsKICBzdGQ6OnN0cmluZyBhIHsiMTIzIn07CiAgc3RkOjpzdHJpbmcgYiA9IHsiMTIzIn07CiAgc3RkOjpzdHJpbmcgYyA9ICIxMjMiOwogIHN0ZDo6c3RyaW5nIGQoIjEyMyIpOwp9&insightsOptions=cpp14&std=cpp14&rev=1.0) (You  have to press the "play" button).

Every one of the different ways to initialise a string is the same. This really surprised me. I started with c++17 and then switched to c++11, which produced something more like what I was expecting.

Does this mean that all init types in c++17 are now the same? - is there a name for this, because I thought uniform init was only with the curly braces `{}` - is everything now uniform init?

Comment: You should see this: https://youtu.be/9-_TLTdLGtc

Comment: You might be looking for [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). In your example, only `b` might require it; `a` and `c` both call `std::string(const char*)` constructor directly. Even before uniform initialization, there was no difference between `c` and `d`, I believe.

Comment: @Alex very interesting, it does explain a lot : )

Comment: @IgorTandetnik hmm... although your explanation maybe right, I don't think I am talking about copy elision/omission - it existed before c++11, but this is a more specific difference between c++11/14 and c++17 (at least that is what my testing in C++ insights is suggesting)